# How is this output coming . Explain (Homework help)

Tags: c++

Find and write the output of the following C++ program code:
Note: Assume all required header files are already included in the program.

```
void Revert(int &Num, int Last=2)
{
 Last=(Last%2==0)?Last+1:Last-1;
 for(int C=1; C<=Last; C++)
 Num+=C;
}

void main()
{
 int A=20,B=4;
 Revert(A,B);
 cout<<A<<"&"<<B<<endl;
 B--;
 Revert(A,B);
 cout<<A<<"#"<<B<<endl;
 Revert(B);
 cout<<A<<"#"<<B<<endl;
}
```

**Answer**:35&4

38#3

38#9

In the first one why B is 4 and not 5.

Comment: The function takes it's second parameter by value, meaning it makes a copy of `B`. Any changes inside `Revert` is made to the copy, and not to `B`.

Comment: The first number is passed by reference, and therefore is changed. The second one is passed by value, meaning that only its copy is changed inside the function.

Comment: Why are you surprised that `B` is unmodified in the first case, but not surprised that it's unmodified in the second case?

Comment: @molbdnilo I was surprised at that too but since I didn't knew why B was unmodified in the first case, I was not raising the issue fo second one

Comment: Thanks for help, now I got your point. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function does not do anything to change the value of `B` (i.e. the second argument). Thus it will simply output what it was before.

Looking more closely your function has the following signature:

`void Revert(int &Num, int Last=2)`

The first parameter is a reference, thus when you change it within the function, the value it is storing (A) will get changed in the original location. However the second parameter `Last` is only received as a copy, thus when the local copy is changed, the original does not.